# How does the IIS 7 / ASP.Net pipeline work?

Tags: asp.net, iis

From an HTTP request all the way to my files (like .asmx)... what are modules, handlers, app pools... etc... 
I don't want to ready a chapter about it. Just a summary paragraph.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Here's an image describing the IIS 6 & ASP.NET pipeline from [Learn IIS.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis):

[image: IIS 6 pipeline]

Here's an image describing the IIS 7 & ASP.NET pipeline from [Learn IIS.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/aspnet-integration-with-iis):

[image: IIS 7 pipeline]

And finally here's an image for the MVC pipeline that Red-Gate put together:

[image: RedGate ASP.NET MVC request handling pipeline poster]

[The pdf can be downloaded from RedGate](https://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/?utm_source=infoq&utm_medium=textad&utm_term=2230&utm_content=nlv-aheadgame-poster-vrc&utm_campaign=antsperformanceprofiler)

Comment: I appreciate it. But this is for MVC. I'm looking for a similar diagram for core IIS 7 pipeline (and ASP.NET in general)

Comment: Snap! Back to the drawing board

Comment: I think they redirected the URL to the pdf. Do you know where I can get this poster?

Comment: @xr280xr here's a [link](https://imgv2-1-f.scribdassets.com/img/document/38856677/original/72424e728b/1570446257?v=1) that works for me as of today. alternatively, refere to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/lifecycle-of-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application