# Can I change the route in my MVC controller depending on if the user is already authenticated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I set up the following route for my application:

```
routes.MapRoute("DefaultRedirect",
    "",
    new { controller = "Account", action = "Login" }
);
```

In my controller I have:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

However if the user is already authenticated I don't want to go to the Account controller and the Login action. Is there some way that I could check for authentication before going to the controller or should I check in the controller and then change to a different controller / action ?

Comment: personally I would check in the destination controller, since it should be called fairly rarely I'd imagine. With that said you 'could' do what you wanted with a custom route handler (you can check forms auth cookies there manually), but why go through the extra work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in route configuration. Routing occurs before authentication in [ASP.NET MVC pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1688810/205859) so you don't have any context to do a switch in route configuration. You need to return another `ActionResult` if the user is authenticated.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. In this case I would like to redirect to the Home controller and Index action. Is it possible to direct to an action in another controller ?